# How to create a Blog using Ghost with the blog post stored in a git repo

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages, ghost-blog, ghost

How do you create a Blog using [Ghost](http://ghost.org) that can be hosted on either Github Pages or Gitlab Pages and the content (blog post which is written using markdown) stored in a git repo?

Comment: Sounds like you want a [static site generator](https://davidwalsh.name/introduction-static-site-generators). Generally, you would checkout the git repo locally, build the site locally with the static site generator, then push the built site up to GitHub Pages. I'm not familiar with Ghost, so I don't know if it can do that. What have you tried? If you're interested, a bunch of static site generators are listed [here](https://www.staticgen.com/) and [here](https://staticsitegenerators.net/).

Comment: I know that you can do that using a static site generator such as Jekyll or Hexo? But I want to know how to do it using Ghost?

Comment: Can you run expressjs on Github pages, I think not

Comment: No you cannot run express js on Github Pages.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use Jekyll or Ghost(using the good old wget in Linux)

I use **Ghost** blog hosted on github pages. Find the instructions and script at https://github.com/abhijithvijayan/ghost-on-github-pages to create one.